# Delta Epsilon Proof of $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln{x}^2}{x}=0$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

I am trying to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln{x}^2}{x}=0$ via the delta epsilon definition of a limit but I keep getting hung up.

I have started the proof like this:

$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta$ so if $\delta>0$, $|\frac{\ln{x}^2}{x}-0|<\epsilon$.

If we suppose that $|\frac{\ln{x}^2}{x}-0|<\epsilon$ and solve for x we get...

When I try solving the inequality for $x$, it keeps cancelling.

What I have tried:

$2x^{-1}\ln{x}<\ln{\epsilon}$

Which becomes:

$2x^{-1}(x^1)<e^{\ln{\epsilon}}$

But then, $x^{-1}$ and $x^1$ multiply to $x^0$, which is $1$ and $x$ is removed from the problem.

Any pointers as how to proceed? I know that the limit is $0$, I just can't seem to get past solving for $x$.

Thank you.

Comment: To typeset $x^{-1}$, use `x^{-1}`.

Comment: Thank you @angryavian

Comment: Hint: $\ln (x^2)=2\ln x$ for all $x>0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... I have started the proof like this:
>
> $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta$ so if $\delta>0$, $|\frac{\ln{x}^2}{x}-0|<\epsilon$.

The $\delta$ in your attempt has nothing to do with $\epsilon$.

By **definition**, given $\epsilon>0$, you need to show that there exists $M>0$ such that
$$
x>M \quad \textbf{implies }\quad |\frac{2\ln x}{x}|<\epsilon\tag{1}
$$

Now for $x>1$,
$$
\ln x=\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}\ dt\leq \int_1^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\ dt=2\sqrt{t}\big|_1^x
< 2\sqrt{x},
$$
which implies that
$$
\frac{2\ln x}{x}<\frac{4\sqrt{x}}{x}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{x}},\quad x>1.
$$
So you want
$
\frac{4}{\sqrt{x}}<\epsilon,
$
which is true if
$$
x>(4/\epsilon)^2.
$$
Now, setting
$M=(4/\epsilon)^2$, you have the implication (1).

Comment: Clever way of showing $\ln x<2\sqrt x$ for $x>1$.

Comment: What does $|_1^x$ mean?

Comment: @limitsandlogs224: $f(x)|_a^b:=f(b)-f(a)$.

Answer (score 4):

$\ln x<2\sqrt{x}$ so 
$$\left|\dfrac{\ln x^2}{x}\right|<\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{x}}<\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{M}}\leq\varepsilon$$
where $x>M$.

Comment: How do you prove $\ln x< 2\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: $\ln x<\dfrac{x^\alpha}{\alpha}$ @user587192 with $\alpha>0$.

Comment: **Proof:** $e^u>u$ therefore $u>\ln u$ let $u=x^\alpha$.

Comment: @Nosrati, thank you. Could you please explain how I could incorporate $\frac{4}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ and $\frac{4}{M^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ into the proof? I thought that I had to solve $\frac{4}{x{\frac{1}{2}}} <\epsilon$ for $x$ so any $\epsilon$ is $>|\frac{\ln{x}^2}{x}-0|$ as long as $\delta>\frac{16}{\epsilon^2}$. I see that they keep $x$ from getting eliminated but I just don't understand how those expressions get substituted into the inequality.

Comment: In fact, it is not difficult to show that $\log(x)<\sqrt x$ for all $x>0$.  Going one step further $\log(x)\le x^{1/e}$ for all $x$ with equality at $e^e$.